# Displaying Datepicker when i click the button

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker, materialize

I would like to display the datepicker when i click on the button. I have tried but i couldn't make it work. I am using Materialize Css. I have tried to use input type text but i don't want it.

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row center">
       <i>Date</i>
       <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light datepicker" type="submit" name="action">PICK DATE</button>
     </div>
   </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, 
    selectYears: 15 
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to show the datepicker from a button, you need to invoke the show option.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jDatapicker JQuery</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
    function show_dp(){
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('show'); //Show on click of button
     }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
  <button onclick="show_dp();">Show Datepicker</button> 
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Another option to make it so you don't need an input field:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jDatapicker JQuery</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>

    function toggle_dp() {
      dp = $("#datepicker");
      if (dp.attr('datepicker')) {
        dp.datepicker('destroy');
        dp.removeAttr('datepicker');
      } else {
        dp.datepicker();
        dp.attr('datepicker', 1);
      }


    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="datepicker"></div>
  <button id="button" onclick="toggle_dp();">Toggle Datepicker</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way is to only show the picker when the button is clicked and not when the input is clicked. This enables the user to edit the input manually as well.

My trick is to use a hidden input to connect the picker to:

```
<div class="input-field datepicker-prefix">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_contact_calendar</i>
    <input type="hidden" class="datepicker" />
    <input />
</div>
```

And then setup the click even to show the picker:

```
$('.datepicker-prefix .prefix').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.datepicker').datepicker('open');
});
```

See my complete solution for both date and time pickers
https://codepen.io/dnote/pen/jXQNpg?editors=1010#0

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code created by me

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jDatapicker JQuery</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. The OP wants to open the picker using a button!